# Adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to a ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating a new ASP.NET Core project using dotnet 4.5.2 and am trying to add a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.  In my project.json file I have these listed under dependencies:

```
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

Looking under References, they appear to be successfully loaded. I then added this under tools in project.json:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
}
```

After I added that, when I build the solution I get this build error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\(my user name)\.nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'
```

I get the same error if I remove the imports line.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue.
I fixed the issue by installing the tools package again in the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre
```

Before reinstalling the package was actually missing in the .nuget\packages.tools folder, after reinstalling it was there.

I followed the https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html tutorial, but I think I installed the package in the wrong order or initially forgot to reference the EF.tools package in the "tools" section of the project json.

Comment: Thanks the link helped a lot. I didn't have to install EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package, althought it was missing in the .nuget path mentioned by the OP. For me, all I had to do was run: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. This automatically restored all my references, and when it finished the package appeared in the above mentioned directory path.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and just solved using the examples from the EF Core setup guide from Microsoft, checking their GitHub code as well, I found this to work for the project.json.

I had to remove the imports from the "frameworks" property, which means no Application Insights for now. Once I did this and built, the folder appeared in the tools folder. Sorry I'm not good at posting code here but here are the important parts, ... elipses used to trim the post of my other things:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
}  ...},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {

}...
```

Comment: Here is the GitHub reference that I used, by the way!!

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/Platforms/AspNetCore/AspNetCore.ExistingDb/project.json

Comment: Sorry, but I played with it some more, and then the error stopped happening.  I'm not sure what I did that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to add the following to my project.json.

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
```

The only difference is that I'm working with the newly release .NET Core 1.1, ASP.NET 1.1 and Entity Framework 1.1.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14170497)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was posting an answer that solved the same issue I came across.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried many things. I found out that Design and Tools need to be the same version but intellisense was not giving me options common to both packages. Then I found this article and tried its code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Using the following code from that article solved the issue for me;

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  }
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
},
...
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had *Microsoft.EntityFrame**W**orkCore.Tools* instead of *Microsoft.EntityFrame**w**ork.Tools*, note the lowercase *w*.